# Can we use either じゃない or ではない in addition to でない for ～ないことには?

Tags: grammar

I found a sentence as follows.

> 体が丈夫**でない**ことには、何もすることができない。

でない is the negation of である.

My question is that

Can we use either じゃない or ではない in addition to でない for the given sentence above?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can say:

> 体が丈夫じゃないことには、何もすることができない。

But you cannot say:

> 体が丈夫ではないことには、何もすることができない。

Perhaps because は is already used after に.

Well, じゃ is explained as the "casual version of では", so I know it doesn't look consistent. I'm not sure, but maybe the "one *wa* per clause" rule can be loosened when じゃ is used?