# Which is more polite, ではまた or じゃまた?

Tags: expressions, politeness, contractions, formality

Context: The terms are used when leaving chat sessions. Some people type deha/wamata and others, jya/jaomata. Which one is more polite?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38325

Comment: Related: https://hinative.com/ja/questions/432010

Comment: Did they type "jaomata", or is that a typo?

Comment: i have seen both spellings in hiragana

Comment: Where have you seen じゃおまた before?

Comment: spelled in chats and じゃお

Comment: 「じゃ**あ**また」の書き間違いでは・・

Comment: You know that じゃ is a contraction of では, do you not?

Comment: i do now from your post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When expressions are shortened, they are usually considered less formal and thus sound less polite. This applies to `では vs. じゃ`: じゃ is less formal and thus sounds less polite (but can sound more friendly). Other common examples include: `しては vs. しちゃ`, `している vs. してる`, `しておく vs. しとく`, `してしまう vs. しちゃう`, `すれば vs. すりゃ`, `しなければ vs. しなきゃ`.